How to prove that support converges to probability?
In the body literature of Association Rule Mining (apriori algorithm is one of them) there's a lot of information about te usage of many metrics, whithin them 'support'.
Support is defined as the frequency of occurrence. In a market Basket Analysis framework it would be the number of times an item (or set of items) was purchased divided by the total number of purchases.
And we see something like:
Antecedent (A) support: $ \#A/N$
And then they refer to it as P(A)
Consequent (C) support: $ \#C/N = P(C)$
Support (S): $\#(A \cup B)/N = P(A \cap B)$
Confidence: $P(C | A)$
Among others...
But I haven't found who actually proved that these relations are true. I assume the proof involves Law of Large Numbers, but I would like to read it :)
Who proved them? Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks a lot!

It has been a few years since I took a data mining course, but aren't a lot of the metrics just counts and normalized counts? Assuming they are IID should be sufficient to conclude that they should converge.

I dont know if IID can be assumed between transactions... In small number of transactions that would not be true, as many of your customers tend to be the same. But as your transactions grow larger I guess we can assume them.
